# Youtube player loads webp image instead jpg

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I have a video player on my site. It is displayed via Youtube iFrame API. Everything is OK, but at the end of the video, in `Chrome`, the player loads the `webp` image ( `https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/******/maxresdefault.webp` ) which doesn't exists. In `firefox` it loads the `jpg` image and it is displayed fine ( `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/******/maxresdefault.jpg` ).

Is there a way to force the loading of the `jpg` image ?

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame code is handled by YouTube, so no.

Indeed I see that the iFrame correctly loads a .jpg where a .webp doesn't exist, usually with old videos. I suspect that this was fixed many years ago.